# Platform Event Loops in C++ Node Addon

Tags: node.js, electron

I am very new to node. I am actually making the switch to using electron as I found it super awesome for rapid/quality/cross-platform development. However I needed to do some platform API stuff on Windows/Mac/*nix. So I was going to follow this guide here:

http://blog.scottfrees.com/building-an-asynchronous-c-addon-for-node-js-using-nan

to create a node addon sort of thing. I have never done this before (kind of new to C++ too), but I am familiar with platform APIs as I used to use it with FFI's. Is it possible to run event loops in it as we do in a typical platform process?

Or is the only option spawning a child process and running event loop in that child-app?

#### Typical winapi (Windows) event loop:

```
MSG msg;
BOOL bRet;
while(1) {
    bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);

    ....
}
```

#### Typical X11/XCB (*nix) event loop:

```
xcb_generic_event_t *event;

 while ( (event = xcb_wait_for_event (connection)) ) {
     switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
        ....
     }
     free (event);
 }
```

#### Typical Cocoa (Mac) event loop:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] run];
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to get an answer to this? I'm in the same shoes trying to access messages provided by C/C++'s `GetMessage` from a Node.js / Electron application.

Comment: I never did @Riverman :( please do share when you solve - i actually moved to another proejct so stopped working on it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Noitidart ! I've been messing around with this for weeks (on and off), and it's driving me crazy :). I'll definitely share if I can come to a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Riverman! :)